# is this possible for radio button? or I misunderstood what he wants

Tags: php, if-statement, colors, radio-button

I'm told to do this

If the user has entered both names and checked a radio button, show a greeting `Hello <firstname> <lastname>`. Change the background color of the Web page to the selected color. You do this by using the echo statement as follows:

```
echo "<body bgcolor =\” $color\”> Hello $firstname $lastname";
```

and my other php file I have

```
elseif(!(empty($_GET["fname"])) && (!(empty($_GET["lname"]))) && ($_GET["bgcolor"] == "red"))
{
echo "<body bgcolor='red'>" . "Hello " . $_GET["fname"] . " ". $_GET["lname"] . "!<br/>" . "Background color changed to the selected color";
}
```

is it possible if I put the the `$_GET["bgcolor"]`'s value into the `<body bgcolor=''>`? so I don't have to use another `elseif` statement...

because seeing this

```
echo "<body bgcolor =\” $color\”> Hello $firstname $lastname";
```

lets me think it's possible but if with just one variable `$color` how is that possible O.o

Comment: Do you want to change color dynamically for any color user has set? Why dont you just edit your echo to `echo "<body bgcolor='".$_GET["bgcolor"]."'>" . "Hello " . $_GET["fname"] . " ". $_GET["lname"] . "!<br/>" . "Background color changed to the selected color";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure it is. But why didn't you try that out yourself ? Would have taken less time than to post this question. :)

For example something like this:

```
$default_color = "white";
[...]
if(!(empty($_GET["fname"])) && (!(empty($_GET["lname"])) && (!(empty($_GET["bgcolor"])))
{
  echo "<body bgcolor=". $_GET["bgcolor"] .">" . "Hello " . $_GET["fname"] . " ". $_GET["lname"] . "!<br/>" . "Background color changed to the selected color";
}
else
{
  echo "<body bgcolor=". $default_color .">" . "Hello " . $_GET["fname"] . " ". $_GET["lname"] . "!<br/>" . "Background color changed to the default color";
}
```

Comment: omg what the hell I can't believe I'm doing two simple mistakes in a day omg...what the hell is wrong with me...

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
 <input type="hidden" value="your-color" name="bgcolor"/>

       if($_GET["bgcolor"] == 'color'){
        $color = 'color'
        }else {
        $color = 'other color'
        }
    echo '<body bgcolor='.$color.'>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one radio button per available color you can do this by saving the color in the value attribute of the radio button. This value will be passed on POST.

```
<input type="radio" value="red" name="bgcolor"/>
```

results in

```
$_POST["bgcolor"] === "red"
```